# Best expression using parallel for sorting a large text file and printing the sum of the second column

Tags: bash, awk, gnu-parallel

Currently I have a large text file in the form of two columns. I am trying to print unique first columns with their sum as the output.

```
cat src   
a 1
b 1
c 1
d 1
a 1
b 2
c 3
d 4
```

With basic awk I am able to achieve the desired output.

```
awk -F" " '{a[$1]+=$2;}END{for(i in a)print i" "a[i];}' src
a 2
b 3
c 4
d 5
```

Issue at hand is the process runs for a large amount of time, if we run the same with a large input file. So attempted to run the same with gnu-parallel and struck on there.

```
cat src | parallel --pipe awk -F" " '{a[$1]+=$2;}END{for(i in a)print i" "a[i];}'
```

Any guidance on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: How big is your file - in bytes? And in lines? What's a *"large amount of time"* please?

Comment: The best way to achieve parallelism in case of a big file would be to define a function that splits your big file into multiple chunks (different line ranges) and call `awk` script in each of those chunks

Comment: @ Mark : Size is close to 1 GB . Lines count 100 million. Using awk tried running it few times and it ran for hours without completing . Looks like awk is not optimised for this large a file size and hence I am requesting for help on adding parallel to further fasten it.

Comment: @Inian : If I am splitting the  file into small chunks, it may lose the overall objective as it might not be reading the other chunks and miss the count actually.  For each and every unique first column, we need to get the total from all files.  Please correct me if my logic is not right.

Comment: Can you give more information about the keys in the first column? Are there only a few or are there nearly as much keys as lines? In your example the four keys repeat. If you knew the number of keys and knew that they repeat in the same order, then you could compute your desired output very efficiently.

Comment: @Socowi : The number of keys will be around 80% of the number of lines. That might certainly be an influential factor in the output of result. One another point we can consider is that the file is sorted hence all the keys are in a sequence. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found [**GNU datamash**](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/) to be the fastest tool for ***standalone*** run in such case.

Test file (https://transfer.sh/hL5xL/file) has ~12M lines and size 116Mb.

Here's an extended time performance statistics:

```
$ du -sh inputfile 
116M    inputfile

$ wc -l inputfile 
12520872 inputfile

$ time datamash -W -g1 sum 2 <inputfile > /dev/null
real    0m10.990s
user    0m10.388s
sys 0m0.216s

$ time awk '{ a[$1] += $2 }END{ for(i in a) print i, a[i] }' inputfile > /dev/null
real    0m12.361s
user    0m11.664s
sys 0m0.196s

$ time parallel -a inputfile --pipepart --block=11M -q awk '{ a[$1] += $2 }END{ for(i in a) print i, a[i] }' \
| awk '{ a[$1] += $2 }END{ for(i in a) print i, a[i] }' >/dev/null

real    0m8.660s
user    0m12.424s
sys 0m2.760s
```

---

For ***parallel*** approach use combination of `parallel` + `awk`.

For the most recent `datamash` version you may try:

```
parallel -a inputfile --pipepart --block=11M datamash -sW -g1 sum 2 | datamash -sW -g1 sum 2
```

As you see, GNU `parallel` was used as the last approach, comprised of combination of 2`awk` commands (one for aggregating intermediate results and another one for aggregating the final results).
The crucial GNU `parallel` options here are:

> **`--pipepart`**
>              Pipe parts of a physical file. **`--pipepart`** works similar to **`--pipe`**, but is much faster.
>
> **`--block-size`** *size*
>              Size of block in bytes to read at a time.

In my test case I've specified `--block=11M` as ~10% of the main file size. In your case you may adjust it to `--block=100M`.

Comment: On my system I tested the first two commands on a file with ~12M lines and 676 keys. The results were very different. `awk` took 5.2 s, but `datamash` took 9.0 s. The results probably depend on the number of keys too, not only on the number of lines.

Comment: @Socowi, and what about 3rd approach?

Comment: @Socowi, No. I don't think you're doing `parallel+awk` approach in a proper way. It should be faster. You can specify your random lines generation scenario, so I could test it

Comment: @Socowi, I've downloaded and tested your file. `parallel+awk` is the fastest one. You may observe my update

Comment: `parallel+awk` is now faster for me too. I have no idea what changed. Even with the old file and old command `parallel+awk` now takes 3.5 s. Sorry for the confusion. I'm absolutely sure that it took 5.2 s multiple times an hour ago. Anyway, my input file may not be representative. OP said the input was sorted. `datamash` takes 9 s on the unsorted, but only 2 s on the sorted file.

Comment: Topic change: Why did you combine `parallel` with `awk` only? Wouldn't `parallel -a sortedInput --pipepart --block=11M -q datamash -Wg1 sum 2 | awk ...` be faster?

Comment: @Socowi, the main 2 new factors which were added later: 1) the OP added *the file is sorted*; 2) the number of keys is much greater than 5. Comparing to the 1st complex answer, I can save `datamash` from sorting a file via `-s` option. But, when combining `parallel` + `datamash` (without `-s`) - the `datamash` is suddenly getting slow. When we specify `-s` option (while the fle is already sorted) - it goes fast. So I chosen  `parallel` + `awk` as a more unified (less tricky for "parallel" approach)

Comment: my `datamash --v` : `datamash (GNU datamash) 1.0.7`

Comment: I have `datamash (GNU datamash) 1.3` and `man datamesh` says, that `-s` *enables* sorting. By default, `datamash` will not sort and is faster without `-s`.

Comment: right now, I have the opposite effect. Perhaps, it's worth to update `datamash`, but in such a need the `awk` stays less tricky

Comment: Thank you all for your inputs. Looks like datamash wins compared to awk. The next best answer was the improved awk of @Socowi.

Comment: Try `--block -1`.

Comment: If `inputfile` is sorted, then use `-k`. This way you can used the "sorted summer" in the final stage, too.

Comment: @OleTange, thanks, `--block -1` allows to save about `0.9s` of time. Not a huge difference, but good to know

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suspect this isn't a problem with `awk`. I've generated a test file, similar to yours, with 100 million lines and about 1 gigabyte in size. There are about 100 thousand unique keys in the first field. On my not-very-fast laptop, your `awk` command runs in just over a minute.

Without knowing anything about your computer, I'd guess the problem is either lack of memory or really slow I/O. On my system `awk` needed about 512 megabytes of memory for 100 thousand keys. If you have millions of keys, you'd need proportionately more memory and could be seeing a problem with low memory causing swapping. Swapping works really badly with hashed arrays and random keys. Or if you are reading the file from a slow network file system or an old USB memory stick, you might just be waiting for I/O, though this is less likely.

I'd suggest you run your command then watch it with `top` to see what is going on. Your `awk` process should be using 100 percent of a CPU. If it isn't, `top` should show problems with swapping or I/O waits. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You said that the input file is sorted, therefore you could heavily improve your `awk` command:

```
awk -F" " '{if (key!=$1) {print key" "sum; key=$1; sum=0} sum+=$2}
           END {print key" "sum}' inputfile
```

This command uses a constant amount of memory instead of a linear amount in the number of keys. As [Jon suspected](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51061104/6770384), memory might be the main slow down in your case.

Since your example file is not sorted, we test the command in a pipe after `sort`

```
$ sort src | awk ...

a 2
b 3
c 4
d 5
```

The additional empty line at the beginning can be removed by adding another `if` in the `awk` command or appending `... | tail -n +2`.

In case your input file is not sorted, this approach is slow, even when using `LC_ALL=C sort` to sort faster (takes half the time on my system compared to just `sort`).

Please note that this is just an improvement of the `awk` command. The [`datamash` command proposed by Roman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51060983/6770384) also benefits from already sorted data and beats `awk`.